# JQuery Autocomplete with countries

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i'm trying to make an autocomplete with country codes in jquery. I'm using this [code](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple) as example. In my site, it works really well, but the values, appear as a list in front of the input, and not like the example in the site. I couldn't run it on jsfiddle, but here is [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/px2dmd1o/). Thanks you!

```
var countries = {
    "Argentina (AR)":"AR",
    "United States (US)":"US",
    "Comoros": "KM",
    "Congo (Brazzaville)": "CG",
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of the": "CD",
    "Cook Islands":  "CK",
    "Costa Rica":  "CR",
    "Côte d'Ivoire": "CI",
    "Croatia": "HR",
    "Cuba":  "CU",
    "Cyprus":  "CY",
    "Czech Republic":  "CZ",
    "Denmark": "DK",
    "Djibouti":  "DJ",
    "Dominica":  "DM",
    "Dominican Republic":  "DO",
};

$( "#countryCodes" )
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
.autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            Object.keys(countries), extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var terms = split( this.value );
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push( countries[ui.item.value] );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join( "," );
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

exactLast function is missing in the fiddle. I added now and here now it works in Fiddle

```
function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/px2dmd1o/1/

Check and let me know what is your issue

Comment: Thanks you! I could solve my problem, i needed to add some css to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to provide the autocomplete with a source array. jQuery's autocomplete expects the source array to contain objects with properties `label` and `value`. You could build this array after defining your `countries` object, e.g.:

```
var mySource = Object.keys(countries).map(function(country) {
  return { 
    label: country, 
    value: countries[country] 
  };
});
```

...and then provide that to the autocomplete:

```
$('#countryCodes').autocomplete({
  source: mySource
});
```

To get your fiddle running I had to comment out the rest of what you were passing to the autocomplete widget because it had some undefined functions.